# Colour difference between Windows and Linux Renders in 2.79

Tags: rendering, color

I have been working on a project for a while, and to speed up the rendering process, I am using 3 computers to render. One with Windows 10, one with Windows 7 and one with Ubuntu. The problem is, the Windows systems and the Ubuntu computer are returning different colours in the render. The settings should be the same, as they are working off of the exact same file, and the modifications to blender are the same.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V-cExcx0ssG_iIKJGQuhMpNUmzmx-Qc8

I hope that someone encountered this problem already, and that there is a solution for it.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Edit: Oh, and I am using GPU render, the Windows 10 and the Ubuntu computer have GTX 1050ti-s, and the Windows 7 one has a GTX 1050. (Also I have Filmic blender installed.)

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the Ubuntu system automatically changed the colour space to an apple display instead of leaving it as sRGB for some strange reason.

Comment: That is not strange at all. People at Ubuntu assuming a lot of things. You get used to it over time ;-)